# Will "Allow louder than 100%" damage my laptop's speakers?

Tags: sound, volume-control, speakers

It seems to me that volume on Ubuntu is somewhat lower than volume on Windows. I've encountered with this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/182423/ubuntu-sound-volume-is-40-lower-than-in-windows).
Now, I want to understand if this option might cause damage to the laptop's speakers or there's no worry.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Some speakers just do fine, however some speakers make the sound distorted, or just output no sound, but it provides no damage to the speaker, most likely.

Comment: Anything to back that up? Like this it may be reassuring, but it's not a good answer.

Comment: I'd also like some sources for backup for this. I've just replaced speakers on my zenbook laptop  like some sources for backup forbecause the left one died within the first year. I routinely ran at >100% volume, and am hesistant to do it again unless thoroughly reassured.